# data validation with list and search

Tags: excel, list, validation, search

Please help! I've created a list fruits(say) on sheet2 and four fruits are listed there, (apple(A1),mango(A2),berry(A3),papaya(A4). Now if on sheet1 if cell A1 contains any value from the list (e.g. papaya) then cell B1 must show fruit and for any other value it must show "no match"

Comment: In cell B1 `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,A1)>0,"fruit","no match")`

Comment: Here's information on the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)